# D600 vs D700 for a portrait photographer

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, nikon-d700, nikon-d600

My wife has been dabbling in semi-pro photography for the last year or so. She has come a long way and feels like she is ready to upgrade to a more serious camera. She mostly does newborns/seniors/family pictures but has dipped her toes into wedding photography with good results.

As we started looking at her upgrade options, it became clear the D600/D700 are the two cameras at our price point that she can move on to. The D700 is unanimously raved about by virtually everyone she knows, but cannot be bought new anymore and most of the used ones with ~10k actuations are selling for roughly $1800 on eBay. We could pay an extra $200 and have a brand new D600 with warranty and all that good stuff, which makes me feel a lot less nervous for the money spent.

So, long story short, for someone doing portrait photography with 2k to spend, would you recommend buying a slightly used D700 or a brand new D600?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The D600 without hesitation.** It is a much newer and more capable model. It is even faster and the higher resolution will let you make much larger prints.

The only studio related thing that the D600 is missing is a Sync-Port to connect sudio flashes. You can get an adapter from hot-shoe to sync-port is you like or go with wireless trigger which is very convenient.

For completeness - but it may not have much an impact on studio photography since most such images are edited anyway - the D600 has a 100% coverage viewfinder while the D700 does not, which frankly is an embarrassment for a full-frame camera but it is not the only offender.

Comment: Have you heard anything about the oil spots on the D600s?

Comment: Yup, there seems to be a consensus among people who own D600's that there is some debris or oil specks that end up on the sensor when the camera is new. One individual took a clean sensor and ran the camera through a few hundred releases and made a short movie out of it: http://kyleclements.com/blog/2012/a-review-of-the-nikon-d600s-dust-problem/. The issue seemed to go away after 1000 or so shots. Even so I'd go for the D600 over the D700.

Comment: Mine had more dust than *usual* but nothing that did not clear up easily with a Visible Dust brush and fluid. If you are mostly shooting in a studio and store your camera with lens attached as I always do, this should be a minor issue.

Comment: The concern was that the dust and other debris was coming from within the camera- the fellow who ran the test didn't remove the lens for the duration. To put it in perspective, oil specks are not uncommon in new cameras...

Comment: Maybe it is a sample variation. Mine for two months never developed this problem. I had a problem like that with another camera and the service department at Pentax swapped the sensor out and the issue never came back. So, I'd say, they'll fix it if it is a problem. Nikon customer service is very good.

Comment: The D600 oil/dust issue is readily addressed, I don't think that's a purchasing factor now.

Comment: I would add the caveat that Nikon Customer Service is good when Nikon decides to actually recognize a problem. Nikon has exhibited a consistent and regular pattern of behavior this year though...and they will refuse to acknowledge certain problems exist for as long as they can, and frequently make their customers jump through hoops to get an issue resolved (often costing the consumer hundreds of dollars in shipping costs back and forth). This was the case with the D800 yellow screen issues, the AF issues, and currently Nikon has not officially recognized the D600 oil issue.

Comment: So, just a word of warning...Nikon can be extremely stubborn about issues, even when the internet community has definitively proven they exist with gobs of visual and analytical evidence.

Comment: @Itai: Can you explain what you mean by the 100% coverage viewfinder? As I said this is for my wife so I don't understand all the terms completely.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino - 100% coverage viewfinder means that the D600 shows you exactly what will make it into the final photo. The D700 has a cropped-viewfinder which shows 95% of what makes it into the final image, so you get a more than what you see. If you want to shoot without cropping images, this is essential, otherwise you end up with an unwanted element in your scene (usually the edge of something, a pole, wire, head, hair, etc - anything that was just out of what you saw in the viewfinder).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to entirely agree with Itai, there are some additional things to consider:

1. The D600 isn't really much faster. 5.5 frames per second burst versus 5 for the D700.
2. The D600 flash sync speed is 1/200 versus 1/250 for the D700. Might not seem like much, but when trying to overpower ambient light (especially sunlight), it starts to matter.

The second point is relevant in wedding situations, especially outdoors. If you want to control the light there, then the sync speed gets quite critical. If most of your work is in a controlled studio, then it's less of an issue, but still an issue. See the Strobist [view on the D600](http://strobist.blogspot.ca/2012/09/nikon-d600-think-twice-before-you-jump.html) for some detail. Either way, you indicate some studio needs and the D600 is actually a little weaker there.

The big upside to the D600 is that it does have improved resolution, about twice, but that has an interesting cost to portrait work... Greater detail may actually mean more retouching. People aren't really fond of that zit being there in all its glory or deep pores looking deep. At any rate, I wouldn't turn the D600 down on that basis, but be aware of that potential.

One final consideration... No video on the D700. If that matters to you (never has for me), then the D700 may be a non-starter.

Comment: Extra resolution is *never* a disadvantage (except w.r.t. data storage/processing), if you're worried about having to do more retouching, simply sun a small radius Gaussian blur over your image and you'll be right back to D700 levels of detail.

Comment: @MattGrum I didn't say it was, I just noted that it may mean more retouching. :) I use the D800, it's scary the amount of detail that comes in and a few D800 portrait photographers have commented on this, not as a negative, but something to be aware of.

Comment: I have heard many people call the D800's resolution a disadvantage, and they own it. File sizes are the main complaint they have.

Comment: @dpollitt - I wouldn't call it a disadvantage, but it's definitely a consideration when using it in a situation where certain levels of detail are actually less desired. As for file size, not really that bad (50mb an image usually), but it depends on your capacity for dealing with them I suppose.

Comment: @MattGrum " .. never a disadvantage ..." - all else being equal. Noise levels will be increased for a given technology and implementation. This will be offset by improvements in technology. How much so is the issue. The eg DxO optics ISO benchmarks are normalised to a 12 mp image. They scale their nouse results by the square root of the megapixels (which I consider  'suspect' for at least some noise). But, using this factor a 24 mp ISO result will be 'improved' by a factor of sqrt(24/120 OR 1.414 X or noise figures will be multiplied by 0.7071 (ie 1/1.414).   ...

Comment: @MattGrum - ...  The D800-D600/D700 ISO ratio are LESS than 1.4:1. ie the D700 has less noisy per pixel figures. ie to make the D600/800 figures better than the D700 by the degree shown you must use the WHOLE image and downscale it to 12 Mp. Even then the difference is somewhat less than 1/2 a stop - something the graphs don't make clear as they plot the scales as log scales for the major axis points (1000, 2000, 3000 ISO) BUT plot the results linearly in between these points. The point is that noise and effective resolution wise the D600 is far closer to the D700 than is usually appreciated.

Comment: @MattGrum fwiw (not much possibly) the raw DxO ISO scores for recent cameraa using THEIR formula ISO rating published = ISO_rating actual x sqrt (megapixels /12) are:
 5D MkIII = 1640, D800 = 1650, D600 = 2110, D700 = 2300, D3s = 3250.

Comment: Doesn't the increased pixel density expose lower quality lenses? I've read many reviews, especially of the D7000, where lens quality was especially important, as well as technique, to get better images compared to previous lower density chips.

Comment: @camflan - I had heard that, especially about the D800, but I think that lower quality lenses were being exposed on cameras with less resolution already and so was poor technique to be fair. A lot of D800 chatter was based on the medium format density and a lot of speculation that MF technique would be needed, but I don't think it played out that way. At any rate, my first Nikon lens purchase was on the recommended list for the D800 and, to be honest, so are the rest of my desired lenses, so I may never really know for sure...

Comment: @Russell In this instance was not talking about noise. The issue is complicated, what you have to do to be really fair is normalize for a certain level of detail, not a certain resolution when comparing noise across different megapixel sensors. I've seen an example featuring a sensor with much higher density that despite having much higher per pixel noise permits a much stronger level of noise reduction to applied before losing detail than a lower resolution sensor. I'll see if I can dig it out...

Comment: @camflan The D800 sensor does not "expose lower quality lenses", a low quality lens will look as good or *better* on a D800 than it will on any other DSLR body. What is true is that you will see a bigger increase in resolution when switching to a D800 if you have a higher quality lens.

Comment: @MattGrum - That would be of interest. I have a Sony A77 and a Nikon D700. I will not be buying a D600 or D800 any time soon. If I had to sell either A77 or D700 I would, very very sadly, sell the D700. Noise performance is excellent - and high ISO performance wise is withing=n half a stop of the very best FX 35mm (D3S) and within 0.4 stop of the D800/D600/D800e cluster. Not much has changed high ISO noise wise despite the apparent gains when linear results are compared. Alas, the A77 utterly trounces the D700 as a photo taking system for my purposes. Hard to believe for long time ...

Comment: Nikon fans. The Sony integration of EVF / live view and brain needs to be lived a while  to appreciate how good it is. Live view is not really a different view - the camera works the same at all times and the rear LCD mirrors what the EVF is showing. Against that the D700 low light performance is a joy but it's a clunky dinosaur to use in high rate of change situations. Say manic street photography, weddings, parties, events  where performers may do unexpected things etc. SO I peer into the future and wonder if Sony are going to yet come to the rescue. Detail/ noise/ MP / real world / .. agh!.